# Correlation coefficient if inputs are the same?

Tags: correlation

I'm using [Pearson product-moment correlation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.corrcoef.html) in Python to calculate how "similar" are the two inputs of the same length. The closer the correlation value to 1.0 the better.

However, when the inputs are completely the same, the above Python function returns "Not A Number". I need something more "user-friendly" than the NaN.

Would it be mathematically justified to say the correlation between those two inputs is -infinite?

Comment: When one of arrays contains only one value (once or many times), then standard deviation for this array is 0, which leads to undefined correlation coefficient.

Comment: OK, but would you say the correlation is "infinite"?

Comment: Not infinite but undefined, because both numerator and denominator turn to zero.